# spark AnalysisException Unable to instantiate SessionHiveMetaStoreClient in second notebook?

Tags: pyspark

I am running spark in a jupyter notebook, and I just figured out what the problem was, but maybe that is useful for others. I am running this code in two notebooks:

```python
import pandas as pd
from pyspark import SQLContext
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3]})

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext.createDataFrame(df)
```

The first notebook returns:

> `DataFrame[x: bigint]`

While the second notebook returns:

> `AnalysisException: Unable to instantiate [...].SessionHiveMetaStoreClient`

Answer (score 0):

Even though the spark context is the same when you get it with `SparkContext.getOrCreate()` something hinders spark to insantiate that object. `sc.stop()` is not enough.

The solution is to **close down the first notebook**, i.e. stop the kernel completely. Then it works in the second notebook. Maybe someone can add an explanation why that happens.